# Find Last cell from Range VBA

Tags: vba, range, cell

How to find location of last cell from defined Range? Cell does not have to contain any data but must be most right and most down located cell from certain Range.

```
Set rngOrigin = wksOrigin.Cells(IntFirstRow, IntFirstColumn).CurrentRegion
```

I wish to receive

```
Cells(i,j)
```

Comment: this may work for a simple case http://www.cpearson.com/excel/cells.htm  with case of set myrange=Range("A1:A10") and using stuff at that link re indexing a range , and using  myrange.Rows.Count

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this is what you want:

```
Dim rngLastCell As Range
Set rngLastCell = rngOrigin(rngOrigin.Count)
```

Comment: Not the most elegant but certainly the shortest. Works for me!

Comment: seems pretty elegant to me!

Comment: It would not work if the range is of rows or columns because for example worksheets(1).rows("1:3").count returns 3 (number of rows) instead than the total numbers of cells of these rows

Comment: The correct safe solution that works for any kind of range would be anyRange.Cells(anyRange.Cells.Count)

Comment: No. Unfortunately these short solutions won't work for noncontiguous ranges like Worksheets(1).Range("a1:b3, d5:e6") :-(

Comment: Thanks for @6diegodiego9 comments. Instead of `worksheets(1).rows("1:3").count`, use `worksheets(1).range("1:3").count` or use what he suggested: `anyRange.Cells(anyRange.Cells.Count)`. And for noncontiguous ranges, the above solution won't work! Another code should check for the largest column and largest row numbers in the given range. To check whether a given range is noncontiguous, use `If rngOrigin.Areas.Count > 1 Then '...`

Comment: quick and elegant

Answer (score 2):

maybe you're after this:

```
'absolute indexes from cell A1
With rngOrigin
    i = .Rows(.Rows.count).row
    j = .Columns(.Columns.count).Column
End With

'relative indexes from rngOrigin upleftmost cell
With rngOrigin
    i = .Rows(.Rows.count).row - .Rows(1).row + 1
    j = .Columns(.Columns.count).Column - .Columns(1).Column + 1
End With
```

Comment: It doesn't give the correct cell for noncontiguous ranges like Worksheets(1).Range("a1:b4, d5:e6")

Answer (score 1):

I handled it in below code but your remarks were helpful. Thank you.

```
intLastRow = rngOrigin.Cells(1, 1).Row + rngOrigin.Rows.Count - 1
intLastCol = rngOrigin.Cells(1, 1).Column + rngOrigin.Columns.Count - 1
```

Comment: then you should adopt my "absolute" code and both avoid repeating `rngOrigin` and use a (to me) more proper range specification

Comment: Your solutions don't give the correct last cell for noncontiguous ranges like Worksheets(1).Range("a1:b4, d5:e6")

Answer (score 1):

The answers given by others mostly work, but not if the region is a union of non-contiguous cells. Here is a version that works consistently for single and multi-area regions, contiguous and non-contiguous.

```
Function LastCellOfRange(rng As Excel.Range) As Excel.Range
  Dim area As Excel.Range
  Dim rowNum As Long
  Dim maxRow As Long
  Dim colNum As Long
  Dim maxCol As Long
  Dim areaIdx As Integer

  Set LastCellOfRange = Nothing

  maxRow = 0
  maxCol = 0
  For areaIdx = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
    Set area = rng.Areas(areaIdx)
    rowNum = area.Cells(area.Cells.Count).row
    If (rowNum > maxRow) Then
      maxRow = rowNum
    End If
    colNum = area.Cells(area.Cells.Count).Column
    If (colNum > maxCol) Then
      maxCol = colNum
    End If
  Next areaIdx

  Set LastCellOfRange = rng.Worksheet.Cells(maxRow, maxCol)
  Set area = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following but it relies upon cells always being populated

```
rngOrigin.End(xlDown).End(xlRight)
```

or you could use the `CurrentRegion` and count the rows and columns and use `Offset`

Alternatively, you could use this construct which works even with ranges based on entire rows or entire columns.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rngOrigin As Excel.Range
    Set rngOrigin = Range("$A$1:$D$6")

    Dim rngLast As Excel.Range
    Set rngLast = rngOrigin.Cells(rngOrigin.Cells.Count)
    Debug.Print rngLast.Address
End Sub
```

Finally, for ranges with multiple areas you'll have to script against a range's Areas collection ...

```
Sub Test()
    Dim rngOrigin As Excel.Range
    Set rngOrigin = Range("$A$1:$D$6,$F$1:$G$6")
    
    Debug.Print rngOrigin.Areas(1).Cells(rngOrigin.Areas(1).Cells.Count).Address
    Debug.Print rngOrigin.Areas(2).Cells(rngOrigin.Areas(2).Cells.Count).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: This is wrong, as the range end property just moves to the last cell within the current region.  End(xlDown) or End(XlToRight) does the same as CTRL+arrowDown or CTRL+arrowRight, starting from the top-left cell of the given range

Comment: @6diegodiego9 thanks for your feedback.  I have amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to code find the last cell in a given range

```
Sub GetLastCellFromRange()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range("$C$10:$E$20")

    'Set rng = Range(Selection.Address) ' Use this line to select the range in worksheet

    MsgBox "Last Cell of given range is : " & rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Address
End Sub
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: It doesn't give the correct last cell for noncontiguous ranges like Worksheets(1).Range("a1:b4, d5:e6")

Comment: Yes, above code is applicable only for continuous ranges

Comment: 'Use this for noncontinuous ranges
Sub GetLastCellFromRange()
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Range(Range("$C$10:$E$20"), Range("$G$10:$H$50"))

    'Set rng = Range(Selection.Address) ' Use this line to select the range in worksheet

    MsgBox "Last Cell of given range is : " & rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Address
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here will work as long as the given range is continuous. This is what I would use for a range that you are absolutely sure is going to be continuous:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myRng As Range, lastCell As Range
    Set myRng = Range("A1:D4")
    Set lastCell = myRng.Cells(myRng.Rows.Count, myRng.Columns.Count)
    Debug.Print lastCell.Address 'returns $D$4
End Sub
```

---

For non-continuous, DB user10082797 gave a great solution, however their function fails when the ranges are positioned diagonal-up (for example, if you pass rng=A3:B4,C1:D2 in you will get D4 as the output which was not part of the original range.)

So the question becomes, what is the last cell in the range A3:B4,C1:D2? Is it B4 or D2? That's a decision for the programmer. Here is a  function I wrote with the help of DB user10082797's function:

```
Function LastCellOfRange(rng As Range, Optional returnLastRow As Boolean = True) As Range
'returns the last cell in @rng.
'if @returnLastRow is TRUE, then the output will always be in the right most cell of the last row of @rng
'if @returnLastRow is FALSE, then the output will always be in the bottom most cell of the last column of @rng
'(@returnLastRow only matters for non-contiguous ranges under certain circumstances.)
    'initialize variables
    Dim area As Range, areaIdx As Long
    Dim lastCellInArea As Range
  
    'loop thru each area in the selection
    For areaIdx = 1 To rng.Areas.Count
        Set area = rng.Areas(areaIdx) 'get next area
        Set lastCellInArea = area.Cells(area.Rows.Count, area.Columns.Count) 'get the last cell in the area
        'if:
        '  the return is empty
        '  OR if the last row needs to be returned and this row is larger than the last area's
        '  OR if the last row needs to be returned and this row is the same as the last area's but has a larger column
        '  OR if the last column needs to be returned and this column is larger than the last area's
        '  OR if the last column needs to be returned and this column is the same as the last area's but has a larger row
        'THEN:
        '  make this cell the return range
        If LastCellOfRange Is Nothing Then
            Set LastCellOfRange = lastCellInArea '(must be seperate from the other statment when its not set to anything)
        ElseIf _
            returnLastRow = True And lastCellInArea.Row > LastCellOfRange.Row _
            Or returnLastRow = True And lastCellInArea.Row = LastCellOfRange.Row And lastCellInArea.Column > LastCellOfRange.Column _
            Or returnLastRow = False And lastCellInArea.Column > LastCellOfRange.Column _
            Or returnLastRow = False And lastCellInArea.Column = LastCellOfRange.Column And lastCellInArea.Row > LastCellOfRange.Row _
        Then
            Set LastCellOfRange = lastCellInArea
        End If
    Next areaIdx
End Function
```

You can use the function like this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim myRng As Range
    Set myRng = Range("A3:B4,C1:D2")
    Debug.Print LastCellOfRange(myRng).Address 'returns $B$4
    Debug.Print LastCellOfRange(myRng, False).Address 'returns $D$2
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

'Use this for noncontinuous ranges

`Sub GetLastCellFromRange()
Dim rng As Range

```
Set rng = Range(Range("$C$10:$E$20"), Range("$G$10:$H$50"))

'Set rng = Range(Selection.Address) ' Use this line to select the range in worksheet

MsgBox "Last Cell of given range is : " & rng.Cells(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count).Address
```

End Sub`

Answer (score -1):

In your case, since you want to find the cell to the most right and down in your `wksOrigin` (defined as Worksheet), you could use the `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)` to get the last cell Row and Column.

```
i = wksOrigin.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row ' <-- get last row number
j = wksOrigin.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column ' <-- get last column number
```

If you want to debug your result, you can add:

```
MsgBox "Last row at " & i & ", last column at " & j
```

Comment: I want to find last cell of Range which is Current Region, not whole Worksheet. If worksheet contain Data which are beyond Current Region I do not want to include them.

Comment: What is your defined range ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want the absolute last cell of a defined range, regardless of whether it has any content, here is a simple solution

```
Dim InputRng As Range    'define a range for the test'
Set InputRng = Range("$F$3:$F$15") 
MsgBox InputRng(1).Address & ":" & InputRng(InputRng.Cells.Count).Address    'This would output the absolute address of defined range'
```

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18793890)

Comment: @Dez: Thank you for the hint, I would do it when I have time.

Comment: @Like I had replied to Dez, I WOULD DO IT WHEN I HAVE TIME. I am working on UDF in excel that performs similar function, and I checked stack first but couldn't find any useful answer for my case. Eventually I got the solution from another website I linked in my answer. I have TESTED it and it WORKS FINE.

Comment: It doesn't give the correct last cell for noncontiguous ranges like Worksheets(1).Range("a1:b4, d5:e6")