# Selecting column range with specific header

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro code but it runs on specific column and on range of 500 only. I wish it should dynamically select column of header 'PRODUCTS' is present. if possible can we increase the limit of 500 to all the data present in column 'PRODUCTS'.

```
Sub Pats()

myCheck = MsgBox("Do you have Patent Numbers in Column - B ?", vbYesNo)
    If myCheck = vbNo Then Exit Sub

endrw = Range("B500").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = 2 To endrw
PatNum = Cells(i, 2).Value
If Left(Cells(i, 2), 2) = "US" Then
link = "http://www.google.com/patents/" & PatNum
Cells(i, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="http://www.google.com/patents/" & PatNum, ScreenTip:="Click to View", TextToDisplay:=PatNum
With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
End With

ElseIf Left(Cells(i, 2), 2) = "EP" Then
link = "http://www.google.com/patents/" & PatNum
Cells(i, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="http://www.google.com/patents/" & PatNum, ScreenTip:="Click to View", TextToDisplay:=PatNum
With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
End With

End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Can I assume that the header `PRODUCTS` will be found somewhere in row 1?

Comment: yes it will be row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first extract the link building part into a separate subroutine ...

```
Sub AddLink(c As Range)
  Dim link As String
  Dim patNum As String
  Dim test As String
    patNum = c.Value
    test = UCase(Left(patNum, 2))
    If test = "US" Or test = "EP" Then
        link = "http://www.google.com/patents/" & patNum
    Else
        link = "http://www.www.hyperlink.com/" & patNum
    End If
    c.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=c, Address:=link, ScreenTip:="Click to View", TextToDisplay:=patNum
    With c.Font
        .Name = "Arial"
        .Size = 10
    End With
End Sub
```

Then I would add a function to find the column...

```
Function FindColumn(searchFor As String) As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
    'Search row 1 for searchFor
    FindColumn = 0
    For i = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i).Value = searchFor Then
            FindColumn = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

Finally I would put it all together ...

```
Sub Pats()
  Dim col As Integer
  Dim i As Integer
    col = FindColumn("PRODUCTS")
    If col = 0 Then Exit Sub
    For i = 2 To ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
        AddLink ActiveSheet.Cells(i, col)
    Next i
End Sub
```

I'll admit I have to use SO to remind myself how to get the last used cell on a worksheet (see [Find Last cell from Range VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363555/find-last-cell-from-range-vba)).

Comment: thanks Mark Iike the way you grouped US and EP . can you help me if text doesnot start with US or EP it should conconate with www.hyperlink.com

Answer (score 0):

The code below will find which column has the header `PRODUCTS` and then find the last row in that column and store it in variable `lrProdCol`.

```
Sub FindProductLR()
    Dim col As Range
    Dim endrw As Long

    Set col = Rows(1).Find("PRODUCTS")
    If Not col Is Nothing Then
        endrw = Cells(Rows.count, col.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    Else
        MsgBox "The 'PRODUCTS' Column was not found in row 1"
    End If
End Sub
```

So replace the following bit of code

```
myCheck = MsgBox("Do you have Patent Numbers in Column - B ?", vbYesNo)
    If myCheck = vbNo Then Exit Sub

endrw = Range("B500").End(xlUp).Row
```

With the lines above. Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks but still it runs on column 2 thats seems to bug me

Comment: Ok, everytime your code references column 2 you need to reference the dynamic selection eg `(Cells(i, 2), 2) = "EP" ` change this to `(Cells(i, col.Column), col.Column) = "EP" `